# Instantiated objects in recursive python function seems to keep / get references to other instances

Tags: python, recursion, instantiation

Using python 3.9, I want to map a directory with it's subdirectories to a Folder class that is structured as such:

```
class Folder:
    path = ''
    sub_folders = list()

    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
```

I use the following code to populate the main folder, and subsequently using recursion fill the subfolders and their subfolders:

```
def get_folder(path):
    folder = Folder(path)
    sub_directories = [f.path for f in os.scandir(path) if f.is_dir()]
    for sub_directory in sub_directories:
        folder.sub_folders.append(get_folder(sub_directory))

    return folder
```

The result of this method is that every Folder has the same list of sub_folders
[Image of the infinite sub_folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2R1g.png)

I recreated the code in C# (with which I'm way more comfortable with), and it works as expected.

I feel like there is something funky going on with the way the references to the Folder objects are being kept and passed on to other objects.

For reference the C# code that works as intended:

```
public class Folder
{
    public List<Folder> SubFolders { get; set; } = new List<Folder>();
    public string Path { get; set; }
}

public static Folder GetFolder(string path)
{
    var folder = new Folder();
    folder.Path = path;
    var subFolders = Directory.GetDirectories(path);

    foreach (var subFolder in subFolders)
    {
        folder.SubFolders.Add(GetFolder(subFolder));
    }

    return folder;
}
```

[Image of result from C# code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGXVu.png)

**EDIT:**

Apparently I created a class-level variable instead of an instance-level variable. This fixed my error:

**EDIT2:**

Removed the class level variables

```
class Folder:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
        self.sub_folders = list()
```

Comment: Working on it - since I think this is an interesting problem. Initial thought: prior to init you have path and sub_folders members. When not attached to self ('this' in C++) these act as 'static' data members and are shared by all instances of the same class. In the __init__() constructor self._thing = thing is what you should do so each instance has a unique class instance of data.

Comment: It is simply that you have made a class-level, not instance-level, variable `sub_folders`.  It is thus **no surprise at all** that it is then shared across every instance ... that’s entirely what class level variables are meant to do.

Comment: @donkopotamus I see, I wasn't aware that I actually created a class-level variable. Thanks! I fixed it now.

Comment: @drw89 ... get rid of the class level `path` and `sub_folders` in your “fixed” version ... they **should not be there at all**.

Comment: @donkopotamus Okay thanks for the info. Seems I have a lot to learn!

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be improved to have Folder.dirs return a list of Folder objects...

Your main logic was obviously correct, just class syntax.
I almost never use the

```
class():
   member = ... # <-- 'static' variable - not sure what python calls this.

   def __init__(self):
   """ """
```

type of thing. Even in the singleton pattern I find this problematic.
I have been bit badly by this usage several times.

My proposed solution:

```
import os

class Folder:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self._path_name = path
        self._dir_names = [f.path for f in os.scandir(path) if f.is_dir()]

    def __str__(self):
        string = 'path: {}'.format(self.path)
        string += '\n'
        string += 'dirs: {}'.format(self.dirs)
        return string

    @property
    def path(self):
        return self._path_name

    @property
    def dirs(self):
        return self._dir_names


def main():
    """ Test the Folder class """
    folder = Folder('.')
    print(folder)

    for sub_folder in folder.dirs:
        folder = Folder(sub_folder)
        print(folder)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```